# Applying MouseHover/MouseLeave Rule to all Links in a Form

Tags: c#, winforms

For my application I wanted the nice 'pointing finger' image to appear when hovering over an image link.

I did this;

```
//MouseHover Event
this.Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
```

However, the effect persisted and the cursor stayed as a pointing finger.

To get around this I implemented a `MouseHover` and `MouseLeave` solution to revert the cursor back to normal.

```
//MouseLeave Event
this.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
```

Perfect! Well not quite, I now have to make these two events for each link on my form. Is there a faster way to do this, to apply the rule to all links (or a collection of links..)?

Comment: is this for a windows form? or web?

Comment: See the tag - winforms.

Comment: oops I realized that :) didn't look at it till now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create custom control for your PictureBoxes with link. Override `OnMouseEnter` and `OnMouseLeave` methods:

```
public class PictureBoxLink : PictureBox
{
    protected override void OnMouseEnter(EventArgs e)
    {
        Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
        base.OnMouseEnter(e);
    }

    protected override void OnMouseLeave(EventArgs e)
    {
        Cursor = Cursors.Default;
        base.OnMouseLeave(e);
    }
}
```

And use it instead of standard `PictureBox` control.

Comment: Excellent, how do I use this control instead? Thanks.

Comment: Worked it out myself - the best way I think.. :)

Comment: @Clev231 just in case you have found some other way :) when you add this custom control to project and compile it, then control will be available in ToolBox under *YourAppName Components* group